# Gridview not working on PageIndexChanging

Tags: c#, gridview, data-binding, datasource, page-index-changed

I'm using gridview without datasource. On `PageIndexChanging` the page is blank.

My backend code is:

```
protected void gridView_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    Gen_Lic_Grid.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    Gen_Lic_Grid.DataBind();
}
```

My front end code is:

```
  <asp:GridView ID="Gen_Lic_Grid" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="Lic_No" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" OnPageIndexChanging="gridView_PageIndexChanging" PageSize="15" Width="110%">
   <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <Columns>
 <asp:BoundField DataField="Lic_No" HeaderText="License No" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Lic_No" />
 <asp:BoundField DataField="UserID" HeaderText="User ID" SortExpression="UserID" />
 <asp:BoundField DataField="Org" HeaderText="Organization" 
                                    SortExpression="Org" />
 <asp:BoundField DataField="UserName" HeaderText="User Name" SortExpression="UserName" />
 <asp:BoundField DataField="SolType" HeaderText="Solution Type" SortExpression="SolType" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Version" HeaderText="Version" SortExpression="Version" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Lic_Type" HeaderText="License Type" SortExpression="Lic_Type" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Meap_Supp" HeaderText="Meap Support" SortExpression="Meap_Supp" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Lic_From" HeaderText="License From" SortExpression="Lic_From" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Lic_To" HeaderText="License To" SortExpression="Lic_To" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Supp_From" HeaderText="Support From" SortExpression="Supp_From" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Supp_To" HeaderText="Support To" SortExpression="Supp_To" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Max_User" HeaderText="Max Users" SortExpression="Max_User" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Max_Mach" HeaderText="Max Machines" SortExpression="Max_Mach" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Mach_IP" HeaderText="Machine IP" SortExpression="Mach_IP" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Mach_MAC" HeaderText="Machine MAC" SortExpression="Mach_MAC" />
</Columns>
<FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
<PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
<SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
<HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
<EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
<AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the datasource before calling `Gen_Lic_Grid.DataBind();`.

```
protected void gridView_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    Gen_Lic_Grid.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    Gen_Lic_Grid.DataSource = MyVariable;
    Gen_Lic_Grid.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Addition: when not using a declarative datasource control like `SqlDataSource`. But OP is not using it so your answer seems to be the solution.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: I think that they meant it to be on one line

Comment: how do you define the `datasource` because honestly, i'm not getting it.

Comment: @Syrion just include NeedDataSource event in your code and bind datasource there. Next time whenever you use databind() it will automatically call that event and you don't need to define ds (datasource) here.

Comment: Okay i'm really sorry for asking stupid questions but what is `myvariable` exactly?

Comment: MyVariable is the datasource you want to bind ?!!! Maybe your dataset, your dataview, whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `PageIndexChanged` event instead of `PageIndexChanging`. I think you haven't used `NeedDataSource` event.